# Get the total of cell values of rows containing same date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am making a dashboard for online food ordering page. As a functionality I need to show total order sales amount per each day, categorized by payment methods when the user click a particular month.
I am able to get the orders of the month and the payment method of each order and the order date but I cannot produce the actual functionality in Vanilla Js or in Vue.

The below images are showing what I tried and what I need to achieve.
Please any suggestions.

Vue code

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      orders: [], 
    },
    
mounted: function() {
  // Call the API the first time
  this.refreshData()
 },

computed: {
    totals: function () {
      return this.orders.reduce((acc, item) => {
        const date = item.date.split('T')[0]
        let dayTotal = acc.find(total => total.date === date)
        if (!dayTotal) {
          dayTotal = {
            date,
          }
          acc.push(dayTotal)
        }

        dayTotal[item.method] = dayTotal[item.method] ? dayTotal[item.method] + item.total : item.total
        return acc
      }, [])
    }
     
  },

methods: {
    // Extract refresh logic into a method
     refreshData () {
   axios.get('https://staging.testing/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?status=completed,processing&per_page=100&consumer_key=123&consumer_secret=456', {
        params: {
            after: convertdate,
            before: convertbeforedate,
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
      this.orders = response.data;
      console.log(response);
      });
      }
      }
      });
```

[image: This is what I am getting now from the API]

[image: This kind if table I need from the above table]

Answer (score 0):

This can question can help you to group data according to date
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802448/how-do-i-group-items-in-an-array-by-date/46802505)

After successfully grouping your data in dates, you can apply a condition check for your payment method

```
let updateDetails = [...];
let finalObject = {};
for(let i = 0; i < updateDetails.length ; i++ ){
  if(updateDetails[i]){
   finalObject[updateDetails[i].paymentMethod] = finalObject[updateDetails[i].paymentMethod] + updateDetails[i].paymentMethod
   //your other conditional code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `reduce` method to create the `totals` list.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    orders: [
      { id: 1, date: '2020-12-21T19:37:40', total: 20, method: 'PayPal' },
      { id: 2, date: '2020-12-20T20:22:47', total: 40, method: 'Cash' },
      { id: 3, date: '2020-12-20T14:42:24', total: 15, method: 'PayPal' },
      { id: 4, date: '2020-12-20T17:02:27', total: 30, method: 'Cash' },
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    totals: function () {
      return this.orders.reduce((acc, item) => {
        const date = item.date.split('T')[0]
        let dayTotal = acc.find(total => total.date === date)
        if (!dayTotal) {
          dayTotal = {
            date,
          }
          acc.push(dayTotal)
        }

        dayTotal[item.method] = dayTotal[item.method] ? dayTotal[item.method] + item.total : item.total
        return acc
      }, [])
    }
  }
})
```

in this case:

```js
Orders

[
  { id: 1, date: '2020-12-21T19:37:40', total: 20, method: 'PayPal' },
  { id: 2, date: '2020-12-20T20:22:47', total: 40, method: 'Cash' },
  { id: 3, date: '2020-12-20T14:42:24', total: 15, method: 'PayPal' },
  { id: 4, date: '2020-12-20T17:02:27', total: 30, method: 'Cash' },
]
```

```js
Totals

[
  {date: "2020-12-21", PayPal: 20}
  {date: "2020-12-20", Cash: 70, PayPal: 15}
]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer....as I am fetching the data through axios in Vue, I need to show the data when the user select the month....I can display it after the main table....so do I need to create another instance for it???

Comment: Using the computed property, as soon as your fetched data is stored in the `orders` property, the `totals` would "update" too.

Comment: Hi, I just copied the code and put in under Vue instance.... I am trying to show the reduce data in a HTML Table....But I am not getting any data in the table....Below is my code....

Comment: <tr
              v-for="(item, index) in totals" 
              :key="item.date"
              > 
                    <td>{{ item.date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.total[0] }}</td>
                    <td v-if="item.total[1]">{{item.total[1]}}</td>
                    <td v-else>0.00</td>
                    </tr>

Comment: <tr v-for="(item, index) in totals" :key="item.date">
    <td>{{ item.date }}</td>
    <td>{{ item['PayPal'] ? item['PayPal'] : 0 }}</td>
    <td>{{ item['Cash'] ? item['Cash'] : 0 }}</td>
</tr>

Comment: If the payment method is dynamic you will have to do something more complex

Comment: @ BillyG, Hi, the payment method is not dynamic.....after using the Html code also the data is not retrieving.....But my other table is getting the data ....

Comment: Hi I just added the Vue part in the question with your computed function....Couldn't figure out what am i doing wrong...

Comment: Could you edit your question to put a sample of the data that you fetch?

Comment: @Tom the `reduce` code will only work if your order object follows this structure `{ id: 4, date: '2020-12-20T17:02:27', total: 30, method: 'Cash' }`. The code has to be modified if your JSON returns a different structure for the `order` object.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the clarification.....my Json objects has different titles for data such as 'date' is 'date_created' and 'method' is 'payment_method_title'