# Javascript - Group array of objects by date using lambdas

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of message objects, like this one:

```
const messages = [
   {
     id: "messageId",
     text: "Hello!",
     date: new Date("2021/01/01")
   },
   {
     id: "messageId",
     text: "Same day!",
     date: new Date("2021/01/01")
   },
   {
     id: "messageId",
     text: "Another day!",
     date: new Date("2021/01/02")
   },
];
```

As you can see, every object has a native JS Date. How can I group all those objects in an array, by day, using JavaScript lambdas? This is the expected result:

```
 [
   {
     day: new Date("2021/01/01"),
     data: [
       {
          id: "messageId",
          text: "Hello!",
       },
       {
          id: "messageId",
          text: "Same day!",
       },
     ]
   },
   {
     day: new Date("2021/01/02"),
     data: [
       {
          id: "messageId",
          text: "Another day!",
       },
     ]
   },
];
```

Comment: What do you mean by `native JS Date`? BTW The code block you wrote is invalid javascript :)

Comment: @a--m A javascript date object

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802448/how-do-i-group-items-in-an-array-by-date/46802505

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `reduce` object to first create object and group by date (year-month-day) and then use `Object.values` to get an array from that object.

```js
const messages = [
   {
     id: "messageId",
     text: "Hello!",
     date: new Date("2021/01/01")
   },
   {
     id: "messageId",
     text: "Same day!",
     date: new Date("2021/01/01")
   },
   {
     id: "messageId",
     text: "Another day!",
     date: new Date("2021/01/02")
   },
];

const object = messages.reduce((r, { date: day, ...rest }) => {
  const key = `${day.getFullYear()}-${day.getMonth()}-${day.getDate()}`
  if (!r[key]) r[key] = {day, data: [rest]}
  else r[key].data.push(rest)
  return r;
}, {})

const result = Object.values(object)

console.log(result)
```