# group by array of objects with condition and custom key

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have below array of objects,

```
[{

    a: 1,
    created_on: '2021-04-23 10:00:01',
}, {
    b: 1,
    created_on: '2021-04-24 09:03:01',
}, {
    b: 1,
    created_on: '2021-04-24 13:03:01',
}]
```

First, I need to group by with date ignoring times.

So,

```
{
 "2021-04-23": [{
    a: 1,
    created_on: '2021-04-23 10:00:01',
  }],
....
}
```

If it were a date like `created_on:  '2021-04-23'`, I could use `lodash/groupBy`.

I still could use it but now it involves some condition to be applied to convert those `created_on` into date format.

Further, I also need to group by those each grouped by date result as such that their `created_on` falls within a time interval.

```
"SALES_SLOTS": [
    {
      "slot": "00:00-04:00"
    },
    {
      "slot": "04:00-08:00"
    }, 
    {
      "slot":"08:00-12:00"
    }, 
    {
      "slot":"12:00-16:00"
    },
    {
      "slot":"16:00-20:00"
    },
    {
      "slot":"20:00-24:00"
    }
  ],
```

So, if `created_on: '2021-04-23 10:00:01'`, it should come in the group,

```
{
  "08:00-12:00": [{
     a: 1,
     created_on: '2021-04-23 10:00:01',
  }]
}
```

So, first results should be grouped by date from created on and then elements in each groups should be further group by defined time slots.

I suppose, if I could use group by condition, I could achieve the desired result.

Comment: Please add the code you've tried. There are questions on grouping based on the date like: [How do I group items in an array by date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802448)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Vanilla JS

---

#### Using `Array#reduce` with `Map`.

1. Grouping by date is fairly simple, you can group the data by `created_on.slice(0, 10)` using a `Map`.
2. Then I've created a helper function `getSlot` that returns a slot based on the time passed. Now, since your slots are fairly wide, testing just the hour part would be sufficient.
3. Next, for every group of date, again group it by time using `getSlot` helper and `Map` and using `Object.fromEntries` you can get the desired object.

**NOTE:** I've used expressions instead of statements inside my code (*using commas, defaulted parameters*) which is just a preferential choice.

```js
const 
  arr = [{ a: 1, created_on: "2021-04-23 10:00:01" }, { b: 1, created_on: "2021-04-24 09:03:01" }, { b: 1, created_on: "2021-04-24 13:03:01" }],
  
  slots = [{ slot: "00:00-04:00" }, { slot: "04:00-08:00" }, { slot: "08:00-12:00" }, { slot: "12:00-16:00" }, { slot: "16:00-20:00" }, { slot: "20:00-24:00" }],
      
  grpDate = Array.from(
    arr.reduce(
      (m, o, _i, _arr, d = o.created_on.slice(0, 10)) => (
        m.has(d) ? m.get(d).push(o) : m.set(d, [o]), m
      ),
      new Map()
    )
  ),
  
  getSlot = (time) =>
    slots
      .find(({ slot }) => time >= slot.slice(0, 2) && time < slot.slice(6, 8))
      .slot,
      
  grpSlot = grpDate.map(([k, v]) =>
    [k, Object.fromEntries(v.reduce(
      (m, o, _i, _arr, slot = getSlot(o.created_on.slice(11, 13))) => (
        m.has(slot) ? m.get(slot).push(o) : m.set(slot, [o]), m
      ),
      new Map()
    ))]
  );

console.log(Object.fromEntries(grpSlot));
```

#### Screenshot of the output

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is what I tried using `momentjs` and `lodash`.

```js
const bookings = [{
  a: 1,
  created_on: '2021-04-23 10:00:01',
}, {
  b: 1,
  created_on: '2021-04-24 09:03:01',
}, {
  b: 1,
  created_on: '2021-04-24 13:03:01',
}];


const groupedByDate = bookings.reduce((acc, e) => {
  const eDate = moment(e.created_on).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  if (acc[eDate]) {
    acc[eDate].push(e)
  } else {
    acc[eDate] = [e];
  }
  return acc;
}, { })
const allSlots = ['00:00-04:00', '04:00-08:00', '08:00-12:00', '12:00-16:00','16:00-20:00','20:00-24:00'];
const grupedByDateAndSlots = _.mapValues(groupedByDate, (ele) => {
  return ele.reduce((acc, e) => {
    const createdOnDate = moment(e.created_on).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    const foundSlot = allSlots.find((slot) => moment(e.created_on).isBetween(moment(`${createdOnDate} ${slot.split('-')[0]}`), moment(`${createdOnDate} ${slot.split('-')[1]}`)))
    if (acc[foundSlot]) {
      acc[foundSlot].push(e)
    } else {
      acc[foundSlot] = [e];
    }
    return acc;
  }, { })
})

console.log(grupedByDateAndSlots)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: seems it works, then what is the problem?

Comment: I tried after @adiga commnet, no problem.

Comment: Got you, I see one problem what if a record is created on exact slots boundary time like `2021-04-23 04:00:00`, in which slot it slot it should be placed? `00:00-04:00` or `04:00-08:00`. I don't think it'll place any of these with existing code.

Comment: Thanks @Ravikumar  for pointing out I will take care of that

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this with simple `reduce` like below.

```js
const data =[{  a: 1,  created_on: '2021-04-23 04:00:00',}, {  b: 1,  created_on: '2021-04-24 09:03:01',}, {  b: 1,  created_on: '2021-04-24 13:03:01',}];

const allSlots = ['00:00-04:00', '04:00-08:00', '08:00-12:00', '12:00-16:00','16:00-20:00','20:00-24:00'].map(ele => ele.split('-'));




const result = data.reduce((acc, ele) => {
  // use can use format() to custom formats
  const [date, time] =ele.created_on.split(' ');
  const slot = allSlots.find(slot => slot[0] <= time && slot[1] >= time );
  if (!acc[date]) {
    acc[date] = {};
  }
  const key = `${slot[0]}-${slot[1]}`;
  if (!acc[date][key]) {
    acc[date][key] = [];
  }
  acc[date][key].push(ele);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```