# How to return incomplete jsx from map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have data in an array of objects as below:

```
history = [
  {item: cake, calories: 120, datetime: 2022-11-16 07:51:26},
  {item: chicken, calories: 250, datetime: 2022-11-16 13:48:46},
  {item: pizza, calories: 420, datetime: 2022-11-25 11:13:42}
];
```

I want to render a div with a heading for the date and group all items with same dates in a list. I am using my map function like below:

```
function renderHistory () {
  let date;

  return props.history.map((item, i) => {
    const dateAdded = item.datetime.split(" ")[0];

    if (date !== dateAdded) {
      date = dateAdded;
      return (
        <>
          <div>
            <h2>{dateAdded}</h2>
            <li>{item.item} - {item.calories} calories</li>
        </>
      )
    }

    return (
      <>
          <li>{item.item} - {item.calories} calories</li>
        </div>
      </>
    )

  })
}
```

I get an error `Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <div>`

If I return like below the second item gets out of the div.

```
return props.history.map((item, i) => {

  const dateAdded = item.datetime.split(" ")[0];

  if (date !== dateAdded) {
    date = dateAdded;
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{dateAdded}</h2>
        <li>{item.item} - {item.calories} calories</li>
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <li>{item.item} - {item.calories} calories</li>
  )

})
```

How do I put all items with same date in a single div?

Comment: `return (<div>  { props.history.map( ... )} </div>)`

Comment: @derpirscher Wouldn't this add a div to all the items in the array? I want the first 2 items in a single div because they have the same date and the 3rd item in a separate div.

Comment: No it wouldn't. It would create a `<div> .. </div>`  and inside this div it would would create the elements you return from `map` Of course, you shouldn't return a `div` from the `map` ...

Comment: And if you want some special grouping, you have to create that beforehand. Ie group your `history` by date first. Then iterate over the groups and create all elements within the group

Comment: First, [group by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802448/how-do-i-group-items-in-an-array-by-date) and then do the `map` on the resulting array and the nested array inside it.

Comment: Ca you try to remove the fragments tags ?

Comment: @adiga Thanks grouping worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import "./styles.css";
const foodItems = [
  { item: "cake", calories: 120, datetime: "2022-11-16 07:51:26" },
  { item: "chicken", calories: 250, datetime: "2022-11-16 13:48:46" },
  { item: "pizza", calories: 420, datetime: "2022-11-25 11:13:42" }
];

const foodItemsGroupedByDate = {};

foodItems.map((foodItem) => {
  const date = foodItem.datetime.split(" ")[0];
  foodItemsGroupedByDate[date] = foodItemsGroupedByDate[date] || [];
  foodItemsGroupedByDate[date].push({
    item: foodItem.item,
    calories: foodItem.calories
  });
});

const foodItemsArray = Object.entries(foodItemsGroupedByDate);

function RenderFoodItems({ items, date }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div>{date}</div>
      {items.map((item) => {
        return <div>{item.item} - {item.calories}</div>;
      })}
    </>
  );
}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {foodItemsArray.map((item) => {
        return <RenderFoodItems date={item[0]} items={item[1]} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Try something like this, tested in codesandbox.

Answer (score 1):

React under hood transforms JSX `<div><h2>text</h2</div>` into

```
React.createElement('div', undefined, React.createElement('h2',undefined,'text'))
```

what are you trying to do is impossible with this architecture.

Instead you need to find some other approach. Maybe group data by date and then render. Something like

```
function renderHistory () {
const grouped = props.history.reduce((acc,item)=>{
  const dateAdded = item.datetime.split(" ")[0];
   return {...acc, [dateAdded]: [...acc[dateAdded], item]}
  },{});

  return Object.keys(grouped).map((dayAdded) => {
     return (
     <div key={dayAdded}>
        <h2>{dateAdded}</h2>
       { grouped[dayAdded].map((item)=>(
         <li key={item.item+dayAdded}>{item.item} - {item.calories} calories</li>)
         )}
      </div>
    )

  })
}
```

Comment: It says unexpected token on this line `return {...acc, [dateAdded]: ...acc[dateAdded], i}`
at the first period here `...acc[dateAdded]`

Comment: sry forgot braces, should work now

Comment: It should be `acc.datetime.split` right? I changed `item` to `acc` since you are using `acc` instead of `item` but now I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: acc.datetime is undefined` and when I log `acc` it's an empty object.

Comment: sry, that `i` should be `item`, acc is that object which will be returned.. ill fix it

Comment: `acc[dateAdded] is undefined`

Comment: I changed the return in your reduce function to this and it worked `if (!acc[date]) {acc[date] = [];}acc[date].push(item);return acc;`