# Arrange Chat message by Date in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have seen this, but it does not solve my problem:
[How do I group items in an array by date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802448/how-do-i-group-items-in-an-array-by-date)

I want to arrange this chat message by date, I have successfully retrieved the message from the database using AJAX.

Here is the retrieved chat in the console.

```
[
    [
        "Paul Abioro",
        "paulexv....@gmail.com",
        "chester",
        "Teejay",
        "Hi Teejay",
        "3",
        "2023-04-06 17:42:54"
    ],
    [
        "Paul Abioro",
        "paulexvi....@gmail.com",
        "chester",
        "Teejay",
        "How are you doing?",
        "3",
        "2023-04-06 17:42:58"
    ],
    [
        "Teejay Bello",
        "tee....@gmail.com",
        "Teejay",
        "chester",
        "I'm Fine",
        "2",
        "2023-04-06 19:00:42"
    ],
    [
        "Paul Abioro",
        "paulexv....@gmail.com",
        "chester",
        "Teejay",
        "Testing",
        "3",
        "2023-04-08 10:12:38"
    ],
    [
        "Teejay Bello",
        "tee....@gmail.com",
        "Teejay",
        "Chester",
        "Testing what?",
        "2",
        "2023-04-08 10:21:09"
    ],
    [
        "Paul Abioro",
        "paul....@gmail.com",
        "chester",
        "Teejay",
        "How can we help you?",
        "3",
        "2023-04-08 10:38:25"
    ]
]
```

What I want to do

```
[
  date": "2023-04-06",
  chat":[
        "Paul Abioro",
        "paulexv....@gmail.com",
        "chester",
        "Teejay",
        "Hi Teejay",
        "3",
        "2023-04-06 17:42:54"
    ],
    [
        "Paul Abioro",
        "paulexvi....@gmail.com",
        "chester",
        "Teejay",
        "How are you doing?",
        "3",
        "2023-04-06 17:42:58"
    ],
    [
        "Teejay Bello",
        "tee....@gmail.com",
        "Teejay",
        "chester",
        "I'm Fine",
        "2",
        "2023-04-06 19:00:42"
    ],

 date": "2023-04-08",
   chat":[
        "Paul Abioro",
        "paulexv....@gmail.com",
        "chester",
        "Teejay",
        "Testing",
        "3",
        "2023-04-08 10:12:38"
    ],
    [
        "Teejay Bello",
        "tee....@gmail.com",
        "Teejay",
        "Chester",
        "Testing what?",
        "2",
        "2023-04-08 10:21:09"
    ],
    [
        "Paul Abioro",
        "paul....@gmail.com",
        "chester",
        "Teejay",
        "How can we help you?",
        "3",
        "2023-04-08 10:38:25"
    ]
]
```

I hope you get the idea. Thanks!

Comment: your final output i believe you are looking for an array of objects?

Comment: Yeah, as long as I have the output grouped by date. It will be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use array `reduce` to group into an object and then take the values array of the reduced object using `Object.values`.
If you want the object grouped by date instead of the array remove the `Object.values`

the date portion can be obtained using
`curr[curr.length-1].split(" ")[0]`
or
`curr.at(-1).split(" ")[0]`
if your environment supports `at`

```js
const a = [    [        "Paul Abioro",        "paulexv....@gmail.com",        "chester",        "Teejay",        "Hi Teejay",        "3",        "2023-04-06 17:42:54"    ],    [        "Paul Abioro",        "paulexvi....@gmail.com",        "chester",        "Teejay",        "How are you doing?",        "3",        "2023-04-06 17:42:58"    ],    [        "Teejay Bello",        "tee....@gmail.com",        "Teejay",        "chester",        "I'm Fine",        "2",        "2023-04-06 19:00:42"    ],    [        "Paul Abioro",        "paulexv....@gmail.com",        "chester",        "Teejay",        "Testing",        "3",        "2023-04-08 10:12:38"    ],    [        "Teejay Bello",        "tee....@gmail.com",        "Teejay",        "Chester",        "Testing what?",        "2",        "2023-04-08 10:21:09"    ],    [        "Paul Abioro",        "paul....@gmail.com",        "chester",        "Teejay",        "How can we help you?",        "3",        "2023-04-08 10:38:25"    ]]

const res = Object.values(a.reduce((acc,curr) => {
  const date = curr[curr.length-1].split(" ")[0]
  acc[date]??={date,chat:[]} //or acc[date] = acc[date] || {date,chat:[]}
  acc[date].chat.push(curr)
  return acc
},{}))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, however, I am trying to loop through each array using a nested while loop 1. first loop for the dates, 2. the nested loop for the arrays in each date.

can you help me with that?

Comment: hi whats causing the issue. also better ask a new  question if it is out of scope of this question so other people also can see

Comment: Okay, I did it. with forEach statement, Thanks @cmgchess

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` to get the result:

```js
const chatArray = [
    [
        "Paul Abioro",
        "paulexv....@gmail.com",
        "chester",
        "Teejay",
        "Hi Teejay",
        "3",
        "2023-04-06 17:42:54"
    ],
    [
        "Paul Abioro",
        "paulexvi....@gmail.com",
        "chester",
        "Teejay",
        "How are you doing?",
        "3",
        "2023-04-06 17:42:58"
    ],
    [
        "Teejay Bello",
        "tee....@gmail.com",
        "Teejay",
        "chester",
        "I'm Fine",
        "2",
        "2023-04-06 19:00:42"
    ],
    [
        "Paul Abioro",
        "paulexv....@gmail.com",
        "chester",
        "Teejay",
        "Testing",
        "3",
        "2023-04-08 10:12:38"
    ],
    [
        "Teejay Bello",
        "tee....@gmail.com",
        "Teejay",
        "Chester",
        "Testing what?",
        "2",
        "2023-04-08 10:21:09"
    ],
    [
        "Paul Abioro",
        "paul....@gmail.com",
        "chester",
        "Teejay",
        "How can we help you?",
        "3",
        "2023-04-08 10:38:25"
    ]
]



const result = chatArray.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const lastIndex = cur.length - 1;
    const date = cur[lastIndex]?.split(" ")[0];
    const chat = cur.slice(0, lastIndex);
    acc[date] = acc[date] ? [...acc[date], chat] : [chat];
    return acc;
  }, {});
  
const chatObjectsArr = Object.entries(result).map(([date, chat]) => ({ date, chat }));
  
console.log(chatObjectsArr);
```